# How to use Azure variable $(build.buildnumber)-$(build.sourcebranchname) in Dockerfile as build artifact/jar is getting generated with buildNumber?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am writing a azure pipeline that will build a jar and a docker image. Most of part is working but I am not able to substitute $version variable in Dockerfile. And I am declaring artifact version as $(build.buildnumber)-$(build.sourcebranchname) as given below. I can not hard code it as with every run of build, builnumber will change.
How can I use either $version or $(build.buildnumber)-$(build.sourcebranchname) in Dcokerfile where I am copying jar to container folder.

My generated artifact name is like this `someservice-api-$(build.buildnumber)-$(build.sourcebranchname).jar`

Azure Pipeline:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download gradle.properties secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: gradle.properties

- powershell: |
    New-Item -Type Directory -Force "${HOME}/.gradle"
    $version = "$(build.buildnumber)-$(build.sourcebranchname)"
    Add-Content "$(Agent.WorkFolder)/_temp/gradle.properties" "`nartifactVersion=$version"
    Add-Content "$(Agent.WorkFolder)/_temp/gradle.properties" "`nartifactDir=$path"
    Copy-Item -Force "$(Agent.WorkFolder)/_temp/gradle.properties" "${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties"
```

other task like gradlew build, copy, publish to staging directory

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/webapp/clientscore
COPY ./build/libs/someservice-api-$version.jar api.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "api.jar"]
```

I have tried with following already

```
COPY ./build/libs/someservice-api-$version.jar api.jar
COPY ./build/libs/someservice-api-${version}.jar api.jar
COPY ./build/libs/someservice-api-$(build.buildnumber)-$(build.sourcebranchname).jar api.jar
COPY ./build/libs/someservice-api-${build.buildnumber}-${build.sourcebranchname}.jar api.jar
```

Azure Docker task:

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
```

Comment: FYI, If I use a hardcode version like $version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" and make corresponding change in Docker file 
COPY ./build/libs/someservice-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar api.jar, then everything works.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on how Azure DevOps maps pipeline variables to environment variables? That answers your question. Or, alternately, did you look at the documentation for how to pass environment variables into a Docker build? The documentation is always a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, @DanielMann I did read about how to pass variable. You can define ARG in Docker file and pass them as build args. But I am not able to do that in Azure pipeline.

Comment: @DevGosain is it helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306821/get-the-data-of-build-repository-localpath-and-used-it-in-my-dockerfile/56313922#56313922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure task, Docker "BuildAndPush", that you are using does not accept build args. You need to define Docker "build" task then you can pass build args and use it accordingly in Dockerfile.

```
--build-arg varname="$(dynamicversion)"
```

Have a lookt at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463392/pass-file-content-as-build-argument-in-azure-devops-pipeline-docker-build-task)